# Optimal handling of AVCaptureSession through app's lifecycle

Tags: ios, swift, avcapturesession, avcapturedevice

After reading a lot of Camera App related Apple examples/internet tutorials/random articles I am left with one uncertainty: **What is the optimal way of handling your Session setup, while taking into consideration the full lifecycle of an app/view?**

It seems like every Camera App I've researched does things differently, without having documented the reason for taking that path: some do a simple setup inside viewDidLoad, others choose viewDidAppear, others do it in viewDidLoad and ultimately check and redo it in case of a setup failure in viewWillAppear, etc.. *(every possible combination appears if you search enough tutorials)*

But what would be the optimal choice, taking into consideration most of the possibilities that can occur during a **camera app**'s lifecycle: failing to setup camera, failing to switch between cameras, app entering background, app closing, etc.

Answer (score 1):

"Optimal" is a subjective term. But I can share the experience:

- Handling the video involves quite a bit of code.
- Very little of that code is actually related to UI

So putting the code inside one of the ViewControllers (or Views) makes no sense. Have a separate class instead. What this class will do:

- Encapsulate the lifecycle of the `AVCaptureSession` (including settings, error handling, processing of the raw frames)
- Provide UI with simple interface, so in UI you don't need to worry about any details on how the video works, and can change UI / video independently.

You also need to start/stop session *several times* potentially. For example: when the app returning from background to foreground.

An "on the napkin sketch" would look like this:

```
class VideoSession {

    // Note that this is private, and will be initialized possibly more than once on start/stop
   private var session = AVCaptureSession()

   // Delegate to process video output, also private (and weak)
   private weak var videoDelegate: AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate?

    // Functions for UI

    func start(videoDelegate: AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate, _ onSessionStarted: @escaping (AVCaptureSession) -> Void) {

        self.videoDelegate = videoDelegate
        setupSession()
        // You can also return `nil` or error if setup failed
        onSessionStarted(self.session)
    }

    func stop() {
        if session.isRunning {
            session.stopRunning()
        }
    }

    // Device and session setup

    private func setupSession() { 
        session.beginConfiguration()
        
        // Setup input device
        device = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video)
        // ...
        // configure input and output
        // ...
        session.commitConfiguration()
    }
}
```

And then UI just needs to call start and stop, and assign the session to its preview view:

```
// Assuming this is the class to display live video
class VideoViewController: UIViewController {

     // Video Session
     let videoSession = VideoSession()
    
     // Video layer

     var videoPreviewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer {
        let previewLayer = layer as! AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer
        return previewLayer
    }

    override public func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        // We can't just start video, we need to make sure we have permissions to
        checkCameraPermissionsAndStartVideo()
    }

    override public func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        videoSession.stop()
    }

    override func onApplicationDidEnterBackground() {
        videoSession.stop()
    }

    override func onApplicationDidEnterForeground() {
        checkCameraPermissionsAndStartVideo()
    }

    private func checkCameraPermissionsAndStartVideo() {
        switch AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(for: .video) {
        case .authorized:
             videoSession.start(
                 videoDelegate: self // or another class
             ) { session in
                  // configure our video layer with the session configured by VideoSession
                  DispatchQueue.main.async {
                       self.videoPreviewLayer.session = session
                  }
             }
        case .notDetermined:
            // Ask for permissions
        // ...
    }
}
```

As you see, `UIViewController` already has quite a bit of work. But at least it will just call start/stop when it needs to, not worrying about details of the video session.

On top of that, if you are planning to capture images - that's yet another relatively big chunk of code. And yet again, no reason for that code to live in UIViewController. Have a separate class for it.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your experience and for the 'napkin sketch'. Wanted to ask, depending on how long the setup and camera start might take (e.g. maybe dealing with an older device or maybe an overheated one) wouldn't choosing to perform these operations in viewDidAppear might cause the user to experience some sort of lag / black screen? Thus, wouldn't be better to place them inside viewWillLoad, so that the user has a better chance of getting an image when the view really does load?

Comment: And also regarding the video session stopping, in the case when the user swipes up to see all background apps but changes his mind and decides to further use it, wouldn't the viewWillDisappear be triggered and stop the current stream? Thus, wouldn't it be better to stop the session in viewDidDisappear?

Comment: The loading is done on `viewDidAppear` because it may be that you need to display permissions screen before going to camera view. So I prefer the view to show up first, then start the camera. Otherwise the permissions prompt may appear on top of black void, which looks weird. I have never seen any visible slow down because of that. But if it is a problem in your app, you could try using viewWillAppear, or show a spinner (test it though first, to not get into "premature optimization" pitfall).

Comment: I used `viewWillDisappear` for stopping because of the processing done in my app to each frame. It's best to not continue processing frames when user is no longer focused on the app. But this again, may be different for your app. The important part I think in the sketch is showing separation of session handling vs UI access to the session.

Comment: I appreciate the extra clarifications and now do understand your perspective regarding the sketch. I think I was just more obsessed with the theoretical analysis of the session to view part, rather than efficient encapsulation. But nonetheless, you've made me think about an aspect that I did not take into consideration. It's always great to hear other viewpoints, cheers!